# PhoneGap - navigator.contacts is undefined

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I can't access to navigator.contacts. I'm using phonegap 3.5 and org.apache.cordova.contacts 0.2.12.

I'm testing with phonegap serve and android 4.4.2.

This is what I have in the config file:

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.contacts" />

<feature name="Contacts">
   <param name="ios-package" value="CDVContacts" />
   <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.contacts.ContactManager"/>
</feature>
```

Implementation:

```
   // find all contacts with 'Bob' in any name field
    var options = new ContactFindOptions();
    options.filter = "Bob";
    options.multiple = true;
    options.desiredFields = [navigator.contacts.fieldType.id];
    var fields = [navigator.contacts.fieldType.displayName, navigator.contacts.fieldType.name];
    navigator.contacts.find(fields, onSuccessA, onErrorA, options);
```

Hope you can help me to solve this.

Thanks

Comment: We will need to see your JS implementation in order to help you.

Comment: Are you able to access other plugins via the navigator object?

Comment: @WillHaley I can access to geolocation via navigator.

Comment: @DawsonLoudon I edit the post with the implementation. Thanks

Comment: Did you install this plugin after an initial build?  This may seem a little weird, but I often have to clear my platform folders, install the plugin, and then rebuild the platform before I can get the plugins to work sometimes.  The only other thing I can think of is that the phonegap app may not support contact access, but I've never tried that plugin with the developer app.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem.

My solution was to place the code block which tries to access the Cordova objects (either the .contacts or the ContactFindOptions)  - only AFTER the page is guaranteed to have been loaded.

As displayed in several samples onDeviceReady is usually a good choice.